# AWS Elastic Beanstalk max request post size

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, cors, dotnet-framework

I have an application consisting of the following:

- Vue.JS front-end website
- Dotnet Core API

From the front-end, I wish to allow the user to upload up to 10 files totaling up to a maximum of 50 megabytes, which I will be storing in S3. To allow the API to accept a request of this size, I added the following attribute on my controller action:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(55 * 1024 * 1024)]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitWorkshopNote() {...}
```

Additionally, I added the following to startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 55 * 1024 * 1024;
});
```

You might notice I made the API accept requests of 55 mb, for some padding. Testing this all on my localhost worked fine.

Nest I deployed the API to elastic beanstalk, where I started getting CORS errors whenever the accumulated file size is over what seems to be about 28 or 29 megabytes (the following example shows a request with a content-length of about (*38042883 / (1024 * 1024)*) = **36mb**):

[image]

[image]

I don't know what's causing the issue. I've tried the following steps to resolve it:

1. Adding an environment variable to EB:

   [image]
2. Adding `client_max_body_size 55M;` to a conf file before publishing the project:

   [image]

I've no idea what else to look at/try. I'd repeat that whenever the accumulated file sizes (or the post content-length, actually) is 27MB or less, there are no CORS issues and everything works.

I don't make use of a AWS WAF at all and the rest of the configuration of the EB environment is fairly default with an application load balancer.